# towards + time frame

Tags: word-usage

Is it grammatically correct and idiomatic to use the word towards with a specific time frame in order to mention an unidentified time as the  following example?

> I woke up towards noon ( it can be some time between 10:30 am and 11
>   am) and after doing some chores I went to do some shopping towards the
>   evening ( it could any time after 4 pm )

Comment: This can easily be looked up.

Answer (score 1):

This seems reasonable to me, and I can find examples on google books of exactly this use.

> The prince woke towards noon with Thalia's evocative touches.... ([source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aYMxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA655&lpg=PA655&dq=%22woke%20up%20towards%20noon%22&source=bl&ots=0QUqoLhnez&sig=ACfU3U1U6WUIg_StcBpSgOa4oTvUFDBALA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVz9PG9OrmAhWAQkEAHUagAZMQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22woke%20up%20towards%20noon%22&f=false))

It seems reasonable in that kind of style of writing.  I'd try to avoid overusing this pattern.  Perhaps its okay to say "I woke towards noon", but then I'd try to rephrase the second sentence as "I went to do some shopping in the late afternoon" (or something similar).